# PHP Fatal error: Non-static method smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Couldnt able to find the exact class it refers. I am trying to call the object of the class `ListViewSmarty`.

> **Fatal error**:  Non-static method ListViewSmarty::ListViewSmarty()
>   cannot be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
>   in src/custom/modules/Contacts/ContactsPopupSmarty.php on line 24

Current File: ContactsPopupSmarty.php

```
require_once 'include/Popups/PopupSmarty.php';
require_once 'custom/modules/Contacts/ContactsListViewSmarty.php';

/**
 * ContactsPopupSmarty for Contacts
 */
class ContactsPopupSmarty extends PopupSmarty
{
    /**
     * Override constructor
     *
     * @param SugarBean $seed   Contacts Bean
     * @param string    $module Module Name
     */
    public function __construct($seed, $module)
    {
        parent::__construct($seed, $module);
        //Invoke CustomListViewSmarty class
        ContactsListViewSmarty::ListViewSmarty();
    }
}
```

The following dosent work:

```
$lv = new ListViewSmarty(); 
$lv->ListViewSmarty();
```

any idea?

custom/modules/Contacts/ContactsListViewSmarty.php is extended with ListViewSmarty

```
require_once 'custom/modules/Contacts/ContactsListViewDisplay.php';
require_once 'include/ListView/ListViewDisplay.php';

/**
 * ContactsListViewSmarty for Contacts
 */
class ContactsListViewSmarty extends ListViewSmarty{

    /**
 * Override Constructor
 */
    public function __constuct()
    {
        parent::__constuct();

        //Invoke CustomListViewDisplay
        ContactsListViewDisplay::ListViewDisplay();
    }
}
```

'include/ListView/ListViewDisplay.php' files:

```
require_once('include/ListView/ListViewData.php');
require_once('include/MassUpdate.php');

class ListViewDisplay {

    public function ListViewDisplay(Request $request = null)
    {
        self::__construct($request);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request = null)
    {
        $this->request = $request ?: InputValidation::getService();
        $this->lvd = new ListViewData($this->request);
        $this->searchColumns = array () ;
    }
```

Comment: can you also include `ListViewSmarty`?

Comment: The problem is that i coulnt able to find the ListViewSmarty function files. I know the concept of extends and :: but too many files linked and its difficult to find the file it presents.

Comment: The files which are incuded have other files incuded and extended. :( that makes it difficult for me to find. @Federkun

Comment: Why did you provide `ListViewDisplay` instead? Either way, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).